# ConfigurationManager loaded within the project itself

Tags: c#, configurationmanager

I have a app.config file loaded with some  values in a project, which i load by

```
var value = ConfigurationManager.AppSetting["myKey"]
```

It works fine if I debug from the project itself, but if I create a new Console Project within the same Solution, then the AppSettings[] seems empty.

Is it possible to specify that my ConfigurationManager ALWAYS should point to the app.config file in the project where the ConfigurationManager is used?

Comment: You are mixing source code layout with runtime behavior.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ConfigurationManager always reads the app.config file from the executing assembly regardless of which assembly it is called from.

So in your case you should add the app setting to console projects app.config file and then even though the call to ConfigurationManager is not being made from within the console project executable itself, the value will be read from its app.config file.

Comment: Thanks. Thats excatly the answer I was looking for :)